# How to set up a back end application on a server

Tags: c#, mysql

I would like to develop a back-end application in C# and install it on a server.

While I know C# and also have done a small Java based back-end for Android App on AWS developed with Eclipse, I do not know where to start with C# and mySql.

Is there a tutorial or any other good place to get a head start?

Comment: When you say "back-end application", are you referring to a Windows Service?

Comment: Unless you have a specific problem a better place to start might be Google.

Comment: No, it's some kind of application that receives data sent from Apps, stores it in a DB and provides data interface to a web application as well as the local apps. ps Google I tried, but did not find anything using the terms above...

Comment: Seems like you're looking for [`ASP.Net WebAPI`](http://www.asp.net/web-api)

Comment: I guess so :-), please write as the answer I would like to accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're looking for [ASP.Net WebAPI](http://www.asp.net/web-api)